# XML editor in C# - now showing fields

Tags: c#, xml, datagridview

I have a problem.

I have one XML file that have datafields that I want to read in a datagridview.

THE XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<DATAPACKET Version="2.0">
    <METADATA>
        <FIELDS>
            <FIELD attrname="ALMO_Exercicio" fieldtype="string" WIDTH="4"/>
            <FIELD attrname="ALMO_MesReferencia" fieldtype="string" WIDTH="2"/>
            <FIELD attrname="ALMO_Saldo" fieldtype="string" WIDTH="17"/>
        </FIELDS>
        <PARAMS/>
    </METADATA>
    <ROWDATA>
        <ROW ALMO_Exercicio="2016" ALMO_MesReferencia="01" ALMO_Saldo="0.00"/>
    </ROWDATA>
</DATAPACKET>
```

The C# file that read this:

```
try
{
    XmlReader xmlFile = XmlReader.Create(ofd.FileName, new XmlReaderSettings());
    ds.ReadXml(xmlFile);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
}
```

So, the only thing that show when I open is:
[software only shows the version of xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMva1.jpg)

What I need to do?

Comment: You're looking at the first table, which is `DATAPACKET`.  Have you tried some of the others (there are 6)? What are you actually trying to show?

Comment: How was the XML created? Is `ds` of type `DataSet`? Your XML file does not look valid for a `DataSet` to me. I think you have to process your XML yourself.

Comment: @CharlesMager I haven't tried, I want to show all data from fields:

ALMO_Exercicio, ALMO_MesReferencia, ALMO_Saldo.

BastianThiede The XML was created from another software (governamental software) that I need write data from my software to send again.
So how I can change my code to process the XML?

Here the link for the full code with xml file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bxgpn5JmX9HdQXZXUzNjRVIzZmc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The link you provided does not work for me.

Comment: Sorry, the dropbox link here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/cdc2ewb0awteyhi/LeitorSiga.7z?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to have to process the XML yourself, you can't just load this into a `DataSet` as-is.

You can create columns from each `FIELD` and then get the row data by finding the attributes of the same names from each `ROW`.  This is pretty trivial with LINQ to XML:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(ofd.FileName);

var columns = doc.Descendants("FIELD")
    .Attributes("attrname")
    .Select(fieldName => new DataColumn(fieldName.Value))
    .ToArray();

var rows = doc.Descendants("ROW")
    .Select(row => columns.Select(col => (string)row.Attribute(col.ColumnName)).ToArray());
```

You can then create a `DataTable` from this:

```
var table = new DataTable();

table.Columns.AddRange(columns);

foreach (var row in rows)
{
    table.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GT9dif) for a working demo.

Comment: Thank you Charles, THANK YOU!  Really appreciate  your help.

Comment: I have one more question:

In your code in fiddle he open the xml texts embbed in the C# source, but I have a button that Open the file that I want, have another tip?

Comment: @LeandroMachado the question code uses the open file dialog file name. Is that what you're after?

Comment: Thanks again for your help! I am curious,  let'me explain what I want to do:

State inspectors require the accounting program generates an XML file with the reference month of data and some data, then we have the aforementioned fields.
My accounting program generates the data already filled in ALMO_Exercicio fields, ALMO_MesReferencia and ALMO_Saldo.
What I need is to open this XML file this player I'm trying to do and compare data in datagridview and change when necessary.
Some sample photos:
http://i.imgur.com/xbQK6vs.jpg

http://i.imgur.com/Jsof8Dy.jpg

Comment: Here I have the link of my actual code: https://www.dropbox.com/s/cdc2ewb0awteyhi/LeitorSiga.7z?dl=0